# Unable to install the "useHistory" in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, react-hooks, react-router-dom

I am doing a google clone (mini project) for that I need to import `useHistory` from `react-router-dom`.

I have followed the below steps:

step 1: `npm install --save react-router-dom` (I used this command in terminal)
step 2: `import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom"` (use this in the top of my file)
step 3: `const history = useHistory()` (use this in my code)

after following this steps I am getting the below error:

> export 'useHistory' (imported as 'useHistory') was not found in
> 'react-router-dom' (possible exports: AbortedDeferredError, Await,
> BrowserRouter, Form, HashRouter, Link, MemoryRouter, NavLink,
> Navigate, NavigationType, Outlet, Route, Router, RouterProvider,
> Routes, ScrollRestoration, UNSAFE_DataRouterContext,
> UNSAFE_DataRouterStateContext, UNSAFE_DataStaticRouterContext,
> UNSAFE_LocationContext, UNSAFE_NavigationContext, UNSAFE_RouteContext,
> UNSAFE_enhanceManualRouteObjects, createBrowserRouter,
> createHashRouter, createMemoryRouter, createPath,
> createRoutesFromChildren, createRoutesFromElements,
> createSearchParams, defer, generatePath, isRouteErrorResponse, json,
> matchPath, matchRoutes, parsePath, redirect, renderMatches,
> resolvePath, unstable_HistoryRouter, useActionData, useAsyncError,
> useAsyncValue, useFetcher, useFetchers, useFormAction, useHref,
> useInRouterContext, useLinkClickHandler, useLoaderData, useLocation,
> useMatch, useMatches, useNavigate, useNavigation, useNavigationType,
> useOutlet, useOutletContext, useParams, useResolvedPath,
> useRevalidator, useRouteError, useRouteLoaderData, useRoutes,
> useSearchParams, useSubmit)

It seems like `useHistory` is not a part of `react-router-dom`.

Unable to import the `useHistory` in the react app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can try following steps:

- Install react router dom. npm install --save react-router-dom.
- ```
  Import the history package from react router dom. import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom"
  ```
- ```
  Assign the history function to a variable (not necessary but. recommended)
  ```
- Use the push() function to redirect the user after a successful login.

Comment: `react-router-dom` has it's own `history` dependency and installing separate versions of `history` can potentially cause problems. Besides, OP appears to be using RRDv6, so even if you install `history` separately it won't change what RRD exports.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using `react-router-dom@6` then the `useHistory` hook was replaced by the `useNavigate` hook.

```
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

...

const navigate = useNavigate();

...

navigate(target);                    // replaces history.push(target)
navigate(target, { replace: true }); // replaces history.replace(target)
```

If you specifically want or need to use the `useHistory` hook then you'll need to install the previous `react-router-dom` version.

```
npm i -s react-router-dom@5
```